# RecyclerView that using GridLayoutManager with background makes different heights visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've made an adapter with a layout like the one I share below. it went well but, the appearance of each item became untidy.

Here is my code :

```
public class TableRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TableModel> data;
    private Context context;
    private Fragment fragment;
    private Dialog dialog;

    public TableRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TableModel> data, Fragment fragment, Dialog dialog) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_table, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvTable.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvState.setText(data.get(position).getStateString());
        holder.bg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(data.get(position).getWarna()));
        holder.tvHtml.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.get(position).getShortInfoHtml()));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView paid;
        private TextView tvTable, tvHtml, tvState;
        private ConstraintLayout bg;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTable = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTable);
            tvHtml = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHtml);
            bg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bg);
            tvState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvState);
            paid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPaid);
        }
    }
}
```

This is for layout item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_button_green"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_transparent_table"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvState"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="This text"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="25dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHtml"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:text="Example Text"
                android:textColor="@color/color_primary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTable" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPaid"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/paid"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It makes my recyclerview have different heights depending on the text.

[image]

I want the items to be the same height per row (maximum height in the row)

[image]

Sorry for my english. I hope someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Give it a fixed height and width rather than wrap content

Comment: try giving max lines to all your textview that may give a fixed height

Comment: I set fix line in my textview. But let me know if there is any solution to set height of item layout depending of highest item per row. Because there is a blank space in my item layout, when i set textview line to 2 and the text in that row is only 1.